# Spring MVC: How to return custom 404 errorpages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a clean way to return customized 404 errorpages in Spring 4 when a requested resource was not found. Queries to different domain types should result in different error pages.

Here some code to show my intention (Meter is a domain class):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMeterDetails(@PathVariable("number") final Long number, final Model model) {
    final Meter result = meterService.findOne(number);
    if (result == null) {
        // here some code to return an errorpage
    }

    model.addAttribute("meter", result);
    return "meters/details";
}
```

I imagine several ways for handling the problem. First there would be the possibility to create `RuntimeException`s like

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class MeterNotFoundExcption extends RuntimeException { }
```

and then use an exception handler to render a custom errorpage (maybe containing a link to a list of meters or whatever is appropriate).

But I don't like polluting my application with many small exceptions.

Another possibility would be using `HttpServletResponse` and set the statuscode manually:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMeterDetails(@PathVariable("number") final Long number, final Model model,
final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final Meter meter = meterService.findOne(number);
    if (meter == null) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        return "meters/notfound";
    }

    model.addAttribute("meter", meter);
    return "meters/details";
}
```

But with this solution I have to duplicate the first 5 lines for many controller methods (like edit, delete).

Is there an elegant way to prevent duplicating these lines many times?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution is much simpler than thought. One can use one generic `ResourceNotFoundException` defined as follows:

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException { }
```

then one can handle errors within every controller with an `ExceptionHandler` annotation:

```
class MeterController {
    // ...
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
        return "meters/notfound";
    }

    // ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{number}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewEdit(@PathVariable("number") final Meter meter,
                           final Model model) {
        if (meter == null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();

        model.addAttribute("meter", meter);
        return "meters/edit";
    }
}
```

Every controller can define its own `ExceptionHandler` for the `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: Uh, no. This does not really work as intended, because with such exception handling within the controller, the HTTP status of the response when a `meter` is not found will still be `200` instead of `404`. You indeed show a nice page for the user, but the browser will recieve a response indicating that the request has been successfully handled.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I just rechecked my code and you are right. The `ResponseStatus` annotation should go on the exception handler. I fixed my answer.

Comment: This actually works, in my sample-project!  But - how would the method handleResourceNotFoundException get access to the actual ResourceNotFoundException instance object (which, I can give specifics to for disiplaying on the error-page) ?

Comment: It's really easy to accomplish: just add the Exception to the signature as follows: `handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException e)`

Answer (score 19):

modified your **web.xml** file.Using following code.

```
<display-name>App Name </display-name>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Access this by following code.

```
response.sendError(508802,"Error Message");
```

Now add this code in **web.xml.**

```
<error-page>
<error-code>508802</error-code>
<location>/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This would be useful, if I wanted to have _one_ customized errorpage for all XyzNotFound cases. But what I want is multiple customized errorpages for multiple different domain classes (one domain class => one errorpage). These might include some hints for the user, where to look further. I clarified my question concerning this.

Comment: With your edited answer I wouldn't be able to return the correct error status code (which is 404) anymore.

Answer (score 13):

You can map the error codes in web.xml like the following

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/400</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500</location>
    </error-page>
```

Now you can create a controller to map the url's that are hit when any of these error is found.

```
@Controller
public class HTTPErrorHandler{

    String path = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value="/404")
    public String error404(){
       // DO stuff here 
        return path+"/404";
    }
    }
```

For full example see [my tutorial about this](http://ekiras.blogspot.in/2015/02/custom-error-404-error-page-in-spring-mvc.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Queries to different domain types should result in different error pages."

Comment: @Ekansh thanks for your answer and link looking for this answer from some time +1

Comment: [Don't be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), please. I fixed your answer because this seems to be an actual attempt to answer, but in the future, disclose your links on your own.

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer for 100% free xml:

1. Set properties for DispatcherServlet

   ```
   public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[] { RootConfig.class  };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[] {AppConfig.class  };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
       return new String[] { "/" };
   }

   //that's important!!
   @Override
   protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
       boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
       if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create @ControllerAdvice:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class AdviceController {

   @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
   public String handle(Exception ex) {
       return "redirect:/404";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = {"/404"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String NotFoudPage() {
       return "404";

   }
   ```

   }
3. Create 404.jsp page with any content

That's all.

Comment: As in some of the other answers: This doesn't answer the question. "Queries to different domain types should result in different error pages." - Reading the question's title isn't enough to fully understand the problem...

Comment: And as of spring 4.2 RC 3 there is a cleaner way to set `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436535/3184859).

Comment: non of other method working. but it's works me.

**note:** Must use servlate api 3.10 lower servlet api not work.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow this article where you can find detailed information about exception handling in Spring MVC projects.

[spring-mvc-exception-handling](http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-exceptionhandler-controlleradvice-handlerexceptionresolver-json-response-example)

@ControllerAdvice may help you in this case

Answer (score 4):

We can just add following lines of code into web.xml file and introduce a new jsp file named errorPage.jsp into root directory of the project to get the requirement done.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Queries to different domain types should result in different error pages."

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to NOT use `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer`.

According to `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(boolean)`: "Note that if DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler is used, then requests will always be forwarded to the default servlet and a NoHandlerFoundException would never be thrown in that case."

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-

**Before**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo.web")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
  }

  // ...
}
```

**After**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo.web")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually your override with empty body is equal to default implementation of this method in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, so you can fully remove the overridden method. Link to `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` property is really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a Netbeans project.I added following lines to my web.xml.It only works when I give the path from WEB-INF folder as follows.

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/view/common/errorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```