# 404 error redirect in Spring with Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As you know, in XML, the way to configure this is:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/my-custom-page-not-found.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But I haven't found a way to do it in Java config. The first way I tried was:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public String Error(){
    return "error";
}
```

And it appeared to work, but it has conflicts retrieving the resources.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that handler method?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect to a custom error page if the user enter an invalid url

Comment: Request handlers are meant to handle requests. `/**` matches all URIs.

Comment: Also check my post here for a proper error handling:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607802/java-how-to-store-object-of-varying-type/41610357#41610357

Answer (score 25):

In Spring Framework, there are number of ways of handing exceptions (and particularly 404 error). Here is a [documentation link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

- First, you can still use `error-page` tag in web.xml, and customize error page. Here is an [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page).
- Second, you can use one `@ExceptionHandler` for all controllers, like this:

  ```
  @ControllerAdvice
  public class ControllerAdvisor {

       @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
       public String handle(Exception ex) {

          return "404";//this is view name
      }
  }
  ```

  For this to work, set [throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-) property to true for `DispatcherServlet` in web.xml:

  ```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ```

  You can also pass some objects to error view, see [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) for this.

Comment: I'm using java config, no xml. How can I add the throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound param?

Comment: You are using application descriptor (web.xml) anyway.

Comment: In web.xml, you declare spring org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet as standart servlet.
Add init parameter to this servlet, as I described above.

Comment: this still involves xml configuration... -1

Comment: @Jaffadog there are people that don't trust in annotation configuration and have to rely on XML config instead...

Comment: @Luiggi the OP was asking specifically for java config based solution

Comment: @Jaffadog and Eugene shows how to use `@ControllerAdvice` which is annotation configuration. The XML configuration is for web.xml file, which you use when working on web environments and when you don't use Spring Boot or something similar.

Comment: @Luiggi: extending `WebApplicationInitializer` instead of web.xml

Answer (score 14):

The most clean solution since spring 4.2 RC3 is using the new `createDispatcherServlet` hook within the class extending `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` (or indirectly through extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`) like this:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    /* ... */

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a global `@ControllerAdvice` (a class that is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`) as described [in the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice). Within the advice you can handle the `NoHandlerFoundException` with an `@ExceptionHandler` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler).

This could look something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class NoHandlerFoundControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        // prepare responseEntity
        return responseEntity;
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks to be the best current practice. One minor note: as of Spring 4.2.3, [AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.createDispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#createDispatcherServlet-org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext-) returns a `FrameworkServlet`, so an additional cast to DispatcherServlet is required. Some additional considerations to implementing this approach may be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40563813/2074605).

Comment: Can `getServletConfigClasses` also be used in `WebAppInitializer`?

Comment: Yes it can. It is done in the full code of my answer above, but stripped away for brevity.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer for 100% free xml:

1. Set properties for `DispatcherServlet`

   ```java
   public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
           return new Class[] { RootConfig.class  };
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
           return new Class[] {AppConfig.class  };
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[] { "/" };
       }

       @Override
       protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
           boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
           if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create `@ControllerAdvice`:

   ```java
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class AdviceController {

       @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
       public String handle(Exception ex) {
           return "redirect:/404";
       }

       @RequestMapping(value = {"/404"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String NotFoudPage() {
           return "404";

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This didn't work for me, my code never go in customizeRegistration and fail with ambigous error message

Comment: Best answer on this question, @Carlos Lopèz please validate it

Comment: Where the `RootConfig.class` came from?

Answer (score 5):

Use code-based Servlet container initialization as described [in the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-container-config) and override **registerDispatcherServlet** method to set **throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound** property to true:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        String servletName = getServletName();
        Assert.hasLength(servletName, "getServletName() may not return empty or null");

        WebApplicationContext servletAppContext = createServletApplicationContext();
        Assert.notNull(servletAppContext,
            "createServletApplicationContext() did not return an application " +
                    "context for servlet [" + servletName + "]");

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);

        // throw NoHandlerFoundException to Controller
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet(servletName, dispatcherServlet);
        Assert.notNull(registration,
            "Failed to register servlet with name '" + servletName + "'." +
                    "Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.");

        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping(getServletMappings());
        registration.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());

        Filter[] filters = getServletFilters();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(filters)) {
            for (Filter filter : filters) {
                registerServletFilter(servletContext, filter);
            }
        }

        customizeRegistration(registration);
    }
}
```

Then create an exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e) {
        return "404";// view name for 404 error
    }   
}
```

Don't forget about using @EnableWebMvc annotation on your [Spring configuration file](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"org.project.etc"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose this method to override rather than the customizeRegistration method? It seems like a lot more stuff needs to be there than just 

 `@Override
 protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration){
  registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound","true");
 }`

Answer (score 5):

In your web configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

Declare a bean as follows,

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

  return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container)       
    {
      ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
      ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html");
      ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");

      container.addErrorPages(error401Page,error404Page,error500Page);
    }
  };
}
```

Add the mentioned html files(`401.html` .etc) to `/src/main/resources/static/` folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is this only for Spring Boot?  I'd love for this to work otherwise since you could also specify the non-404 error pages.

Comment: It's for spring mvc. Doesn't matter whether it is spring boot or not... same configuration. You can add error pages for other http error codes as well.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`, `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer`, and `ErrorPage` are not found in Spring Framework 4: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/

Comment: Just to clarify, `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` is part of Spring Boot, so this will only work if you're using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

For Java config there is a method `setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(boolean throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound)` in `DispatcherServlet`. By settting it to `true` I guess you are doing same thing

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

then you can can this `NoHandlerFoundException.class` in controller advice as stated in above answer

it will be like something

```
public class WebXml implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));


        DispatcherServlet dp =  new DispatcherServlet(context);
        dp.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", dp);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed [in comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574869/404-error-redirect-in-spring-with-java-config/34698556#comment46243666_24509564) really works:

```
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration)
{
  registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Spring 5 and Thymeleaf 3.

In `MyWebInitializer`, enable exception throwing with `setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound()`. We need to do casting to `DispatcherServlet`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        ...

        @Override
        protected FrameworkServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
            var dispatcher = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
            dispatcher.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
            return dispatcher;
        }
    }
```

Create a controller advice with `@ControllerAdvice` and add error message to the `ModealAndView`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handle(Exception ex) {

        var mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
        mv.setViewName("error/404");

        return mv;
    }
}
```

Create 404 error template, which displays the error message. Based on my configuration, the file is `src/main/resources/templates/error/404.html`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Resource not found</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>404 - resource not found</h2>

<p>
    <span th:text="${message}" th:remove="tag"></span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

For completeness, I add the Thymeleaf resolver configuration. We configure the Thymeleaf templates to be in `templates` directory on the classpath.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.zetcode"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    ...

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        var templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return templateResolver;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In springboot it is even simplier. Because of Spring autoconfiguration stuff, spring creates a bean `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties`. This class is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mvc")` and therefore it will seek for properties with spring.mvc prefix.

Part from javadoc:

```
Annotation for externalized configuration. Add this to a class definition or a
* @Bean method in a @Configuration class if you want to bind and validate
* some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).
```

You just have to add to your i.e. `application.properties` file following properties:

```
 spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound=true
 spring.resources.add-mappings=false //this is for spring so it won't return default handler for resources that not exist
```

and add exception resolver as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResponseStatusHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handle404() {
        var out = new ModelAndView();
        out.setViewName("404");//you must have view named i.e. 404.html
        return out;
    }
}
```