# Handle request that doesn't match any controller's request path, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I would like to display custom 404 error page if a user enters a request path that isn't handled by any controller.

Suppose that I have only one controller and it handles the following request paths: `path1, path2 and path3`. How can I display a custom 404 error page if a user enters `path4`? Currently, Tomcat displays its own 404 error page. I would like to use annotations and not implement this task by configuring any xml files.

My current approach doesn't achieve this requirement.It might be possible to configure any filters, but I am not aware of such approach. Thus, I will appreciate any ideas about it.

Here is my code:

```
public class WebAppContextInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigWebApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register(WebContextConfiguration.class);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(annotationConfigWebApplicationContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active","demo");
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleConflict() {
        return "404_error_page";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it hitting the `handleConflict()` method when `NoHandlerFoundException` is thrown?

Comment: no, it doesn't hit it.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574869/404-error-redirect-in-spring-with-java-config

Comment: Well, my configuration is exactly the same as stated at the link above but it doesn't provide me with the desired result ...

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but can you change the modifier of your GlobalControllerExceptionHandler to public and try again?