# Spring 4 with Java config: Overriding createDispatcherServlet for custom 404 page not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am running Spring 4.3.7 in combination with Spring Security 4.2.2 and configured it using Java config, so no web.xml. Now I want to get a custom 404 page and the way to go seems to be overwriting the createDispatcherServlet Method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279705/why-are-there-2-ways-to-handle-static-resources-in-spring-addresourcehandlers-a/40563813#40563813) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574869/404-error-redirect-in-spring-with-java-config/31436535#31436535) to throw an exception if a page cannot be resolved. I want to use a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver to handle it and return my custom 404 page, but throwing the exception does not even work for me yet. I hope the configurations given below are enough.

**MvcWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("resourceUrlEncodingFilter",
                new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext)
    {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        [...]
    }

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
    }

    @Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new MappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.setProperty("UserNotAccessibleException", "access");
        mappings.setProperty("VersionsModelCreationException", "versions");

        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        exceptionResolver.setDefaultErrorView("index");
        exceptionResolver.setExceptionAttribute("exception");
        return exceptionResolver;
    }
[...]
}
```

I still only get a

```
 WARN in DispatcherServlet.java:noHandlerFound:1172: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/root/notexisting] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

instead of an exception that I might handle with my SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. Any advice?