# How to handle 404 page not found exception in Spring MVC with java configuration and no Web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, annotations

I want to handle 404 page not found exception in my Spring MVC web app, I'm using `SPRING 4.2.5.RELEASE`, I had read several question regarding this topic but the similar questions are using a different spring java configuration.

I have a Global Exception Handler Controller class that have all my Exceptions, this class works fine but I can't handle a 404 page not found exception.

This is the approach that I take following a tutorial

1) I created a class named `ResourceNotFoundException` that extends from `RuntimeException` and I putted this annotation over the class definition `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`

like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException { 

}
```

2) I created this method in my exception's controller class

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {

    return "notFoundJSPPage";
}
```

But still when I put a URL that doesn't exist I get this error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI"

The questions that I had read said that I need to enable to true an option for the Dispatcher but since my configuration it's different from the other questions and I don't have a `Web.xml` I couldn't apply that.

Here it's my Config.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"config", "controllers"})
public class ConfigMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Here is my WebInitializer

```
public class WebInicializar implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ConfigMVC.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);


    }
}
```

Here is my Global Exception Handler Controller

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {


    @ExceptionHandler(value = NullPointerException.class)
    public String handleNullPointerException(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("A null pointer exception ocurred " + e);

        return "nullpointerExceptionPage";
    }


    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleAllException(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("A unknow Exception Ocurred: " + e);

        return "unknowExceptionPage";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {

        return "notFoundJSPPage";
    }

}
```

And the class I created that extends Runtime Exception

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting this line in my `onStartup` method in the `WebApplicationInitializer.class`

this it's the line I add `servlet.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");`

this is how it looks the complete method with the new line I added

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ConfigMVC.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
}
```

Then I created this controller method in my `GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class`

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public String handle(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {

  return "my404Page";
}
```

and that solved my problem I deleted the `handleResourceNotFoundException` controller method in my `GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class` since it wasn't necessary and also I deleted the exception class `ResourceNotFoundException.class` that I created

Comment: This should work, but the current best practices (as of Spring 4.2.3) are described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436535/2074605).

Comment: @vallismortis The current best practice is to extend AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ? Ho-hum.

Answer (score 2):

You can also extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and override this method:

```
@Override
protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
    final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return dispatcherServlet;
}
```

OR this one:

```
@Override
public void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
}
```

And finally in your `ControlerAdvice` use this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public String error404(Exception ex) {

    return new ModelAndView("404");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in any controller and create a 404 page

```
@GetMapping("/*")
public String handle() {
    return "404";
}
```

Comment: It works but I would use `@GetMapping("/**")`to cover also sublevels of domain

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer by zygimantus didnt work for some reason, so if you also have the same problem , then instead of declaring an "@ExceptionHandler", add one of these to a "@Configuration" class instead.  I put mine in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Bean
  public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver(){
      HandlerExceptionResolver myResolver = new HandlerExceptionResolver(){

        @Override
        public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) {
              //return your 404 page
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("404page");
            mav.addObject("error", exception);
            return mav;
        }
      };
      return myResolver;
  }
```

But make sure you also follow the rest of zygimantus ie

```
dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```