# Spring MVC redirecting unnecessary urls to particular url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a website with following urls:

```
www.example.com/dashboard
www.example.com/user
www.example.com/user/message
www.example.com/pagenotfound
```

Now, what I want to achieve is that whenever user type urls other that above, I want then redirected to page not foung page.

```
e.g. www.example.com/otherurl
     www.example.com/otherurl/otherurl
     so on... will redirect to www.example.com/pagenotfound
```

How can I achieve this in spring MVC framework?

Comment: Check here: all you need is to handle 404 Exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574869/404-error-redirect-in-spring-with-java-config

Comment: Thank you very much. Its really what i needed.