# spring rest Handling empty request body (400 Bad Request)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-4

I am developing a RESTful app using Spring4.
I want to handle the case when a POST request contains no body.
I wrote the following custom exception handler:

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class MyRestExceptionHandler {
     
      @ExceptionHandler
      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
      public ResponseEntity<MyErrorResponse> handleJsonMappingException(JsonMappingException ex) {
          MyErrorResponse errorResponse = new MyErrorResponse("request has empty body");
          return new ResponseEntity<MyErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }   
      @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
      public ResponseEntity<MyErrorResponse> handleDefaultException(Throwable ex) {
        MyErrorResponse errorResponse = new MyErrorResponse(ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<MyErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
    }
    
     @RestController
     public class ContactRestController{
        @RequestMapping(path="/contact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public void save(@RequestBody ContactDTO contactDto) {...}
     }
```

When it receives a POST with no body, these methods aren't called.
Instead,
the client gets a response with 400 BAD REQUEST HTTP status and empty body.
Does anybody know how to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried `@ExceptionHandler(JsonMappingException.class)`?

Comment: Yeah. The same behavior.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I solved the issue
(the custom exception handler must extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`).
My solution follows:

```
        @ControllerAdvice
        public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
            @Override
            protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
                HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
                HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
                // paste custom hadling here
            }
        }
```

Comment: will it invoke only for post methods ?

Comment: When combined the solution from these 2 links:
It worked for me exactly the way I wanted.
Solution Links:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643988
2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41308274

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I need to handle all requests that have invalid parameters. So I extend my class with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and override the method `handleMissingServletRequestParameter`. You can find your own handlers defined inside the class `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class YourExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        // Log and return
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // Do your code here
        return new ResponseEntity<>("YOUR REQUEST PARAMS NOT MATCH!");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and it didn't work for me because the `component-scan`package provided didn't include the package where my `@ControllerAdvice` was provided.

My XML had :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bandi.rest" />
```

My package had a typo `com.bandi.test.spring.exception`. After changing it to `com.bandi.rest.spring.exception` it started working.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SpringRestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleNoMethodException(HttpServletRequest request,
            NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex);
        errorResponse.setErrorMessage("resource not found with exception");
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleDefaultException(Throwable ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex);
        errorResponse.setErrorMessage("request has empty body  or exception occured");
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Also, if you need to handle scenario where your requested resource was not found (bad URL), then  you'll have to add another configuration to your dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Complete Working code is available [here](https://github.com/bandikishores/jersey-spring-hibernate-webapp/blob/master/raml-jersey/src/main/java/com/bandi/rest/spring/exception/SpringRestExceptionHandler.java)

Comment: I am using Spring Boot so i don't need to do additional xml configuration.Spring finds all annotated beans. I will check your example later

Comment: Probably you need to add annotation based config then. As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436535/1925997) Also can you verify if your `@ComponentScan` annotation includes the ExceptionHandler's package?

Comment: In general my ExeptionHandler is working. All errors exept that in the topic are handled. Even NoHadlerFound exeption. I am using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30193013/7022735) advice to enable it.

Comment: Eventually found a solution.

Comment: can you please post solution you found?

Answer (score 2):

If You already have a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and don't want to create new one, You could use this piece of code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleMissingRequestBody(Exception ex) {
    return handle(BAD_REQUEST, ex);
}
```

It should have the same behaviour as **rvit34**'s solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the controller class, I putted below method and it solved my issue. no need of controller advise or any other. Just overriding spring default exception with our user exception with body itself will solve the issue.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MissingServletRequestParameterException.class})
    ApiError handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex) {

        return new ApiError(ErrorCode.MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMS, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue, after spending lot of time debugging the issue I found the jackson is not properly deserializing the `ErrorResponse` object.

This was because I didn't added the getters and setters for the field defined in the `ErrorResponse` object. I was initializing the fields using constructor and there were no getters and setters defined for those fields.

**SOLUTION:**

So when I updated my `ErrorResponse` object from

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import java.util.List;

@JsonRootName("error")
public class ErrorResponse {

  private String message;
  private List<String> details;

  public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }
}
```

to the following one with getters and setters

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import java.util.List;

@JsonRootName("error")
public class ErrorResponse {

  private String message;
  private List<String> details;

  public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public List<String> getDetails() {
    return details;
  }

  public void setDetails(List<String> details) {
    this.details = details;
  }
}
```

Jackson is now deserializing the `ErrorResponse` properly and I'm getting the serialized body in the response.

Answer (score 0):

override `handleExceptionInternal` method handles all the exceptions, so you don't need to override each handle methods:

```
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers, 
HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        MyErrorResponse myErrorResponse = new MyErrorResponse();
        MyErrorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(myErrorResponse, status);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    @ResponseBody
    public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public BaseResponseBean badCredentialsException(BadCredentialsException ex, WebRequest request) {
        BaseResponseBean responseBean = new BaseResponseBean();
        StatusBean status = new StatusBean();
        status.setEnErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        status.setCode(403);
        status.setSuccess(false);
        responseBean.setStatus(status);
        return responseBean;
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public BaseResponseBean badRequestException(HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest ex, WebRequest request) {
        BaseResponseBean responseBean = new BaseResponseBean();
        StatusBean status = new StatusBean();
        status.setEnErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        status.setCode(400);
        status.setSuccess(false);
        responseBean.setStatus(status);
        return responseBean;
    }
}
```