# validate json payload in spring boot rest to throw error if unknown property or empty property has been sent as part of json payload

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

JSON Request:

```
{
    "notificationType" : "ISSUER_OTP1ee2asasa",
    "content" : "hi fff this is fff template content for SBI email good and mobile dfdfdfd and remaining balance is 333 and your name is hahaha.",
    "medium" : "EMAIL",
    "asa":"ddddd",
    "":""
}
```

POJO:

```
package com.innoviti.notification.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;


@Document(collection = "NotificationTemplate")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false)

public class NotificationTemplate {
  @JsonCreator
  public NotificationTemplate(@JsonProperty(value="notificationType",required=true)String notificationType, 
      @JsonProperty(value="content",required=true)String content, @JsonProperty(value="medium",required=true)String medium) {
    super();
    this.notificationType = notificationType;
    this.content = content;
    this.medium = medium;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "NotificationTemplate [id=" + id + ", templateId=" + templateId + ", notificationType="
        + notificationType + ", content=" + content + ", medium=" + medium + "]";
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String templateId;

  public String getTemplateId() {
    return templateId;
  }

  public void setTemplateId(String templateId) {
    this.templateId = templateId;
  }

  private String notificationType;
  private String content;
  private String medium;

  public String getMedium() {
    return medium;
  }

  public void setMedium(String medium) {
    this.medium = medium;
  }

  public String getNotificationType() {
    return notificationType;
  }

  public void setNotificationType(String notificationType) {
    this.notificationType = notificationType;
  }

  public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }


}
```

Controller where payload is posted.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/config", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<NotificationTemplate> configureTemplate(
     @Valid @RequestBody NotificationTemplate notificationTemplate) {
    NotificationTemplate notificationTemplatePersisted = null;

    logger.info(
        "Printing payload of template on server side" + ">>>" + notificationTemplate.toString());
    try {
      validatePayLoad(notificationTemplate);
      notificationTemplatePersisted =
          notificationTemplateService.createNotificationTemplate(notificationTemplate);
    } catch (Exception de) {
      logger.info(String.format("Error in saving template", de.getMessage()));
      throw new RequestNotCompletedException(de.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<NotificationTemplate>(notificationTemplatePersisted,
        HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

Question:How do I validate that an uknown property has been sent as part of payload.In Existing implementation,@RequestBody maps the json without any issue.I want to throw error or validate payload if incoming json is not confirming exactly to POJO.For e.g in payload example i gave,I want to be able to throw error saying that asa is not recognized property

Answer (score 3):

The Jackson property that controls this behaviour is [FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES). This needs to be true in your case, to get the behaviour you describe.

It seems that since spring boot 1.2 this is set to [false by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.2-release-notes#jackson-defaults).

To set it to true add this line to your *application.properties* file:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

And then you will get a `JsonMappingException` when there are extraneous properties in a JSON payload

Comment: I thought that should be the purpose of the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation, namely to override this setting on the POJO level. It seems that it is ignored however.

Answer (score 1):

```
One can add this class int their project and it would throw an exception if json is mismatched to the pojo class properties.

 @Configuration
public class Config implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter converter;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        configureJacksonToFailOnUnknownProperties();
    }

    private void configureJacksonToFailOnUnknownProperties() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter = converter.getMessageConverters().stream()
                                                                            .filter(mc -> mc.getClass()
                                                                                            .equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class))
                                                                            .map(mc -> (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) mc)
                                                                            .findFirst()
                                                                            .get();



        httpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful to block the request from getting processed when any unknown field(s) are sent in JSON request. Also getting a Bad Request 400 error response now, But the only additional thing I am looking for is, how to set a custom message for Bad Request 400 in this case.

Comment: When combined the solution from these 2 links:
It worked for me exactly the way I wanted.
Solution Links:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643988
2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41308274