# How to validate unwanted request body parameters for POST method in Rest API in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, validation

the request body contains data as below
{
"name":"hi",
"age":10,
"hi":""
}

But In Rest Controller I'm trying to get those data with the help of DTO, RestControllerDTO.class

public RestControllerDTO {

@Notblank
private String name;

@Notblank
private Integer age;

// getter and setters

}

Now I want to throw an exception as "hi" is an unknown field before entering into the controller class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do exactly?

Comment: if you are using jackson for json deserialization, try setting `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true` in *application.properties*, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901823/13527856)

Answer (score 1):

You do this by using @Valid annotation in your controller method

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public void bar(@Valid RestControllerDTO dto, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
...
```

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

I would also suggest adding @NotNull as @NotBlank only checks for ""