# Spring : Exception handler does not catch exception for wrong enum value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When calling myPOstMethod of RESTful app , I got error "400 bad request" with no response body

The method definition is

```
@PostMapping()
public MyResponseDTO myPostMethod(
            @Parameter(description = "Paramdescription")
            @PathVariable String tokenParam,
            @RequestBody MyRequestDTO requestBody
    ) 
    {   
        //fill response ...
        return new MyResponseDTO(datafilled);
    }
```

MyRequestDTO has field definied as following

```
public class MyRequestDTO extends BaseDTO {

    ......

    @Override
    public ExpType getExpType() {
        return super.getExpType();
    }
    
}

public enum ExpType {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
}
```

The error occurs when request value which is NOT contain in the Enum (for example VALUE5 )

I am using

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292788/spring-rest-handling-empty-request-body-400-bad-request?rq=1) I am using GlobalControllerExceptionHandler annotated with @ControllerAdvice

With method to catch all exceptions defined as following

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Object> handleGeneralException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
    .....
}
```

But seems that this method does not called

What should be correct handler definition for such case ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the @RequestMapping of the controller? how does the request you are sending look like? is there any error in logs?

Comment: Here is sample request sent : {  
   "searchString":"some search str",
   "type" : "VALUE5",
   "description": "some description" 
}   , The problematic field is TYPE . Did not found errors in log .

Comment: can you update the question and share the whole `MyRequestDTO` and `BaseDTO` ? probably it is a json deserializing issue

Comment: May be helpful: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576320/10231374](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576320/10231374)

Comment: EmanuelTrandafir , birca123 - Thanks - I succeeded to catch the exception - it is HttpMessageNotReadableException with "JSON parse error..".

Answer (score 1):

This may be a parameter parsing error: JSON parse error.

fixed:

```
@ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
```

Comment: Thanks - added overridden handler for HttpMessageNotReadableException

Comment: Ok, I'm glad my answer is useful. If you think my answer is useful, can you give me some Reputation?