# Java how to store object of varying type

Tags: java

I am currently using Spring MVC and Hibernate to develop my web app. Still learning inner workings of java.

I find my self in a situation where I need to store data in a field that could accept different type of Objects along with some other strings of data. More precisely I want to create a ReturnObject that could hold messages, error code...etc.  This way my return JSON could stay consistent through out the api.

This is how I created my ReturnObject

```
public class ReturnResponse {

//Set fields
private Object returnObj;      <----- Need this to accept different types
private HttpStatus httpStatus;
private String message;
private String developerMessage;

// Start build

public ReturnResponse(){
    this.returnObj =        returnObj;
    this.httpStatus =.....etc.
}

// Setters... getters...
}
```

`private Object returnObj;` so that this field could accept Collection, Maps, Class..etc but is this safe?

I seem to remember that its always a good practice to declare specific object type in the field to ensure type-safe.

**Questions**

1. Do you see foreseeable problem in the future, is there a better way of doing this?
2. If this is not type safe, how would I make it safer.

Comment: change `Object returnObj` to `Serializable returnObj`

Comment: I think you only should return the expected message. If there is an error, you should do this with an error handler. This way you also avoid this dilemma and the code is more readable imho.

Comment: The problem with Object is that it can accept any object and you have to perform casting to access members within it. And since it can possibly accept any objects, you may have a hard time trying to determine what class should you downcast it to. (just my past experience)

Comment: how wide is range of types? Is this a kind of "domain"? Maybe inheritance from IMyBasicPiecieOfData helps You

Comment: If you return json maybe you should consider using a library such as jersey, coupled with for example jackson, to handle a proper rest endpoint. json is json, it´s just a string. The object mapping is not done at the rest point side (at least not necessarily) but on the caller side.

Comment: Just to clarify something: most of rest endpoint consider `json` as a type itself. (through annotations such as `@return json`)

Comment: @Sebas I have a controller that uses Jackson lib to convert to JSON.  This ResponseObject is just something to keep all response consistent.

Comment: @HerrDerb Yes I have a service layer that uses error handler and I use a controller is this where I will set the error message to this Response Object

Comment: @user3437460 well noted.. I think you are right

Comment: @JacekCz thank you I will check this out...

Comment: @JacekCz Class and Map for now....

Comment: @EricHuang particulary Class seems strange for me. How You imagine network push/pull? Is this classic Java RPC remake? My intuition say: design problem in wider context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic :

```
public class ReturnResponse<ObjectType> {

    private ObjectType returnObj;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private String message;
    private String developerMessage;

    public ReturnResponse(ObjectType returnObj, /*other parameters...*/) {
        this.returnObj = returnObj;
        // set other parameters
    }

    public ObjectType getReturnObj() {
        return this.returnObj;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It will work if you know when you instanciate your `ReturnResponse` what's the type of the returned object.
I use this pattern in most of my API without problem.

Comment: Because my ReturnResponse will have other fields like String message and such.  Can I move `<>` to the field?  `private Object<T> returnObj`?  would this work?

Comment: @EricHuang I omitted the other fields of your example but you can add them without problem. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *"to store data in a field that could accept different type of Objects along with some other strings of data."* then you need to have a base class for that object which in your case will probably be **Object**.

The problem is that you need to have some way to decipher later in your code, what type of object that is - which in most cases I think will be undesirable and will require unsafe casting.

Only way I can think of to make it more safe is to make some kind of wrapper like:

```
public class Bean {
   private String string;
   private Integer integer;
   private List<String> list;
   private Bicycle bicycle;


   //setters
   //...

   public Optional<Bicycle> getBicycle() {
      return Optional.ofNullable(bicycle);
   }

   //... and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error handler should be in the controller and it should respond an http error. That means a correct HTTP error status, and a desired error message. An error should not look like a successful request (No status code 200). It's an error. In your front end you should handle the http error response accordingly.

With spring this can be very easy a nicely done. Here is an example of an error handler of a project of mine. It's an own class with the annotation `@ControllerAdvice`. spring will automatically use that.

This class will automatically catch any unhandled exception that are defined with `@ExceptionHandler` and send in my case a `ShortExceptionResponse` that contains the type and the message of the exception thrown, with a correct Http error status defined with `@ResponseStatus`.

In your front end you can react accordingly to the different HTTP status error codes. It's nice and generic.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionResponseHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SetRestController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public @ResponseBody
    ShortExceptionResponse noSuchElementExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("An error occured processing a rest request", ex);
    return new ShortExceptionResponse(ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {EntityAlreadyExistsException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public @ResponseBody
    ShortExceptionResponse entityAlreadyExistsExceptionHandler(EntityAlreadyExistsException ex) {
    LOGGER.debug("A rest request could not been process due an illegal state of the target entity", ex);
    return new ShortExceptionResponse(ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class, UnsupportedOperationException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ShortExceptionResponse illegalArgumentExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("An error occured processing a rest request", ex);
    return new ShortExceptionResponse(ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ShortExceptionResponse httpMessageNotReadableExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("An error occured processing a rest request", ex);
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
        return new ShortExceptionResponse(new InvalidValueException(((InvalidFormatException) ex.getCause()).getOriginalMessage()));
    }
    return new ShortExceptionResponse(ex);
    }
...
...
}
```

In the actual controller you just keep throwing the exception and it will be handled by your error handler

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
MetadataDTO createMetadata(@RequestBody MetadataDTO metaDataDTO) throws EntityAlreadyExistsException {
    MetadataDTO result = metaDataService.createMetadata(metaDataDTO.getName(), metaDataDTO.getDescription(), metaDataDTO.getType());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  This is really clean way to handle exceptions.  I was using try and catch blocks thats why I was thinking of creating an ReturnObject so I can set error message to it...  I notice you explicitly set HttpStatus, if an exception is thrown wouldn't it automatically send not 200 status code?

Comment: The default general http error code of a server side exception would be 500. But if a client sends a request with bad parameters or so on, it's not the servers fault. So a 500 would be wrong. It still works of course. Also with different error code, I can react different ways to them in my front end.

Comment: I think your code is 100% better than what I had before.....and I really appreciate your answer.  I have up voted your post....

Comment: Glad to help :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'model' class to store the full object to be converted to json:

```
@AllArgsConstructor //or make a constructor with all the fields manually
class ResponseObject {
    User user;
    House house;
    Car car;
}
```

Since you are using Spring, you already have the Jackson library. So you can do:

```
@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper; // no need to configure anything to use this
public String getJson(){
    User user = new User("user", "password");
    House house = new House(4, true, ...);
    Car car = new Car();
    ResponseObject resp = new ResponseObject(user, house, car);
    String json = null;
    json = objectMapper.convertValue(resp, ResponseObject.class);
    // or:
    try {
        json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
    // or: (would need to use a google Gson dependency)
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    json = gson.toJson(resp, ResponseObject.class);
    return json;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need the flexibility,

```
@Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;
public void printJson() {
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonMap.put("number", 5);
    jsonMap.put("String", "string");
    jsonMap.put("kanky", 987L);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
    System.out.println("json: " + json);
} // works fine if your map values have a toString defined
```