# Creating Custom Exception for Resource Not Found 404 SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8

I do have a class `CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` with 2 methods one for handling wrong formats and the other one when a resource (url) is requested but does not exist. I would like to give the user a custom message instead of the default White Label Error page of Spring. **I'm trying to understand why my `handleResourceNotFoundException` method from `CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is not called when a non existing URI is requested** but instead I keep having the White Label Error page. Thanks for your help!

```
curl localhost:8080/doesnotexist
```

This is my `CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleAllWrongFormatExceptions(WrongFormatException ex,
        WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(true));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex,
        WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Simple class for holding custom error details

```
public class ErrorDetails {

private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;

public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {

    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
} }
```

And here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class StringManipController {

@Autowired
private StringProcessingService stringProcessingService;

@GetMapping("/")
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
public String home(@RequestParam(name = "value", required = false, defaultValue = "") String value) {

    return "Welcome to the String Processing Application";
}

@GetMapping("/stringDedup")
@ResponseBody
public ProcessedString doManip(@RequestParam(name = "value", required = false, defaultValue = "") String value) {

    String result = stringProcessingService.getStringManipulation(value);

    return new ProcessedString(result);

}

@GetMapping("/writeNumber")
@ResponseBody
public ProcessedString getWriteNumber(
        @RequestParam(name = "value", required = false, defaultValue = "") String value) {

    String number = stringProcessingService.getNumberToWords(value);

    return new ProcessedString(number);

} }
```

And here the `ResourceNotFoundException class`

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 266853955330077478L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    } }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574869/404-error-redirect-in-spring-with-java-config/31436535#31436535

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used Spring Boot:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NoHandlerFoundException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> noHandlerFoundException(Exception ex) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("test");
    }
}
```

or

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(
            NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "Test", headers, status, request);
    }
}
```

In the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` class there is a variable called `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`. If this is set to `true` a method called `noHandlerFound` will throw a `NoHandlerFoundException`. Your exception handler will now catch it.

Add this property to your `application.properties` file: `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true`

Comment: I use spring boot 2. In my case, this is not a solution. `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` runs earlier and it does the next 

if (resource == null) {
   logger.debug("Resource not found");
   response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
   return;
  }

Any workaround in mind?

Comment: The ResponseEntityExceptionHandler has many methods that you may provide an implementation, one of them is NoHandlerFoundException, the full list: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html. Try also set spring.resources.add-mappings=false