# Http Status 404 error handling spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, http-status-code-404

How can I implement custom http error handling in spring mvc.

For example: 
I have a url http://localhost:8080/demo/canvas

It display my canvas page but if the user missed the url and typed http://localhost:8080/demo/canva

It shows me Tomcat Rendered HTTP Status 404.
I want it to be custom jsp page.

Comment: Try to post your web.xml nd the controller class

Answer (score 2):

In your `web.xml` you can provide a custom error page mapping based upon the error code:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/PageNotFoundError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This jsp file will be present parallel to `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Hope this will help for Spring specific 404 error page redirects:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages

Comment: ok i resolved it. The mapping in web.xml was conflicting with the spring exception configuration in dispatcher-servlet.xml. TThank's Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Working in my application,, try this

```
    </web-app>  
      <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/404.jsp</location>
      </error-page>
    </web-app>
```

Note: Make sure u restart server each time wen u make changes in web.xml