# Impossible to throw html code error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, encoding, error-handling

I've been trying to make it work for hours, but I just can't.

I have a java web application using spring mvc.

I modified my web.xml to handle html code errors:

```
...
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>my/path/to/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
...
```

I know it works well, because in my code I was using HttpServletResponse to send an error, which would be catch by the server and than return that page.

I was doing it this way:

```
response.sendError(404);
```

*Note that it's not written that way, I'm just simplifying because I know that part works*

But I didn't like that way, for my unit test to work out, I had to get the status, so I added in my code `modelAndView.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`.

At first I thought it would throw the error the same as `response.sendError`, but it looks like not. So I had to set the status and than throw error with `HttpServletResponse`.

So I asked myself if I could remove the `HttpServletResponse` and just return the `HttpStatus` so it would get my error page in my web.xml.

I handed up changing the signature of my method from `public ModelAndView` to `public ResponseEntity<ModelAndView>` and I tried `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);`

And other stuff found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin):

But it returns a white and empty page. From the navigator, if I inspect element, I don't see anything.

It won't even return the page normally if I return `ResponseEntity.ok(modelAndView);`

I saw it was possible to do something such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages), but I think it would just be better to use HttpServletResponse and throw error even if I'm setting the status.

Plus, it's not really a big deal for the moment, because the error pages are in english, but when the page is loaded after being "trigger" by HttpServletResponse, it won't load the charset I'm setting in the page, which I do that way;

Before `<html>` tag

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

After `<head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

So that's why I want to avoid the `HttpServletResponse.sendError`. If I try to access a page that doesn't exist, the server knows it, so it will call 404 page itself, that way to charset is correct.

But that is not my problem.

Thanks for any help about that spring mvc error handling.

Comment: The `ResponseEntity` coz it returns the complete object as Json so it can used with javascript approach. You have to write a JavaScript code which when receiving this Json checks the status code and show/hide DIV section for Not Found, Server Error, etc.