# how to redirect 404 error to html page in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In spring i have a code to redirect onto jsp paje:

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

But when i try to use html page with

```
<location>/WEB-INF/templates/404</location>
```

or

```
<location>/WEB-INF/templates/404.html</location>
```

it shows me 404 standart error, not mine error page.

Comment: Use a exception handler. Look at the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following code and let me know if this worked for you

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

or

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```