# Best way to return added value on Http Status Code 404

Tags: http, api-design

At times I return, at server level, some extra information alongside with a `HTTP 404`

For example, instead of returning just a `404`, which can puzzle my client whether the routing is correct or not, it will also receive something like

> the identifier 'abc' is unknown

I usually set the content type to `text/plain` and return some text in the `Content`

Another alternative is to set the `ReasonPhrase` instead.

Which one is the best way / convention? Set `Content` or set `ReasonPhrase`?

Answer (score 2):

The error message should be put in response body (`Content`), not in response `Reason Phrase`.

According to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)：

> The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short textual description of the Status-Code...The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase.

Some explanation:

1. Reason-Phrase is **short**, **textual** description of **Status-Code**, it should describe Status Code itself, not custom error message. If custom  error message is very long, or the message has JSON structure, using Reason-Phrase certainly violates the specification.
2. As the specification indicate, the client (browser) is not required to examine the Reason-Phrase, which means Reason-Phrase may get ignored for some browsers, in some time.

Comment: a) RFC 2616 is obsolete, see RFCs 723* instead
b) that said, the reason phrase doesn't exist in HTTP/2 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom error responses and overrides the 404 and any other error you want
visit here
[Spring MVC: How to return custom 404 errorpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages)

Create a view and set this code in app/Exception/Handler.php :

/*Render an exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

*/

public function render($request, Exception $e)

{

```
if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)

{

    return response()->view('missing', [], 404);

}

return parent::render($request, $e);
```

}

Set this use to get it working :

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

For more info you can visit

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: My question is not so much on how we can do it but if it is actually a good idea doing it.

Comment: No its not a good idea, Because if the client is performing any specific action on 404 have to change their code make it compatible with your code or they might don't know how to do it. Sometimes its good to follow standards..... I would no recommend that.