# Spring-Boot 2 with Angular

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am  using Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE  with Angular 2.  Currently I  keep  my  Angular  code in  /static  directory.   This is  deployed in an external (not embedded)  tomcat 9.

Default Spring boot  error controller returns WhiteLabel html error page   response if the request comes  from the  browser and  json error response if the request is a rest request.

How can I  override  default  whitelabel error  page  with   custom html  error page if the request comes from a  browser  but still get the  json error response  if  the  request is a  rest  request ?

Comment: are  you using angular js or Angular(>=2.0)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages you can check this answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC: How to return custom 404 errorpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created  public/error  folder and  put  specific error  pages in the folder. WhiteError page  is  replaced  by the error pages