# How to implement a Spring ErrorController where Sonar does not complain?

Tags: spring-mvc, sonarqube

I've implemented a custom error controller to show the user custom error views. I followed a tutorial (can't find it anymore), so my controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()) {
                return "error/403";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error/404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error/500";
            }
        }
        return "error/default";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

}
```

So far so good, but since May 17, 2019 SonarQube complains about a `@RequestMapping` without a method. So I added the 4 methods I am using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT,
            RequestMethod.DELETE })
```

But Sonar now complains that I have too many methods. So what is the correct way to implement a custom ErrorController that complies with [this Sonar rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S3752_java.json)?

Comment: Simple -- //nosonar ;P:P

Comment: @Antoniossss, yeah, as a last resort I would go for this, but I don't like any line of code or comment just to make a validation tool happy.

Comment: But you want to tweak your code upside down to make validation tool happy?

Comment: @Antoniossss Most of the rules make sense and I think it is worth while to tweak the code if it doesn't result in a complete refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that is your "default error page" route, it will always be GET due to redirection, so you can safely change to `@GetMapping`.

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought of that. So even there is an error in a POST the error controller will be executed as a GET?

Comment: Ye because you you will get redirection to /error - and that will be finalized with GET by the browser.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Spring will _not_ send a redirect back to the browser but will redirect to the ErrorController internally - and request sent to the ErrorController will have the same method as the original request that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this and write in web.xml

```
<display-name>App Name </display-name>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

[Spring MVC: How to return custom 404 errorpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages)

Comment: I don't have a web.xml I am using Spring-Boot and beside the application.properties everything is done in code and not XML, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the specific Sonar rule using `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S3752")`, like this:

```java
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @SuppressWarnings("squid:S3752")
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
    }
```

It is better to disable just this specific rule using `@SuppressWarnings`, rather than, as suggested in a comment, disabling Sonar completely for the line using `//NOSONAR` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10971968/350692)).

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56472741/350692) by Antoniossss (changing to `@GetMapping`) is unfortunately not correct.
Spring will not send a redirect back to the browser but will redirect to your `CustomErrorController` internally - and the redirected request will use the same method as the original request that caused the error.
If you limit the `handleError()` method to only handle the `GET` method the client will get a `405 Method not allowed` response if the original request was a `POST`.